# CSS: Stop parent element flash when using pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a basic hover transition using pseudo elements. The transition works fine, but the element "flashes" when it begins.

#### Any idea on how to get around the transition flash?

*Issue recreated in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/xaqKm)*.

I've tried using `-webkit-backface-visibility` to `hidden` to solve the issue. It stops the flash but it hides the `::before` pseudo element from view.

html:

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="cl">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" />
    <span>meoww!</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
div {position:relative;}
span{ 
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:50%;
  color: black;
  text-align:center;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 25px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size: 1.35em;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.cl {
    padding: 0 20px;
line-height: 0;
}

.cl::before,
.cl::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.cl::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.cl::after {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.cl:hover::before,
.cl:hover::after,
.cl:focus::before,
.cl:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.cl:hover::before,
.cl:focus::before {
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(75px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(75px);
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(75px);
}

.cl:hover::after,
.cl:focus::after {
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-75px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-75px);
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-75px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.cl {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/xaqKm

Comment: for whatever reason adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` didnt work for me.  either way this solves it now